# HTML Form Concatenate Inputs into One Field (with GET)

Tags: html, forms

Long story short:

```
<form action="example.com/" method="get">
    <input type="hidden" name="q" value="one,two,">
    <input type="text" name="q">
</form>
```

The goal is that, when the user inputs e.g. "three", the website

```
example.com/?q=one,two,three
```

is called, instead of `example.com/?q=one,two,&q=three`.

A solution *without* JavaScript would be ideal, but I suspect that's not possible.

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using an array then you can try using this solution

```html
<form action="example.com/" method="GET">
    <input type="hidden" name="q[]" value="one">
    <input type="hidden" name="q[]" value="two">
    <input type="text" name="q[]">
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
</form>
```

this way you will get an array of values on submit then you can handle it on server side. But if you just still want to use your method then Javascript is required. With javascript you can get formdata then append the user input to the form then send it using ajax.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's not possible without using Javascript as far I know.
it's better if you handle this at the backend.

But, if you really want to do at the front-end, you can do as follows (With vanilla Javascript).

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(){   
    let form = document.getElementById('form');
    let query = '';
    let valueObj = {};

    if(form){
        form.addEventListener('submit', (e) => {
            e.preventDefault();
            let exceptinput = ['submit','reset','button','file','image'];
            let allElem = e.srcElement;            
            if(allElem.length > 0){
                createValueObj(allElem, valueObj, exceptinput).then(data => { 
                    console.log(data);                    
                    query = serialize(data);
                    window.location = 'http://www.example.com/?' + query;                  
                }).catch(err => {
                    console.log(err);
                })                                
            }     
        });
    } 





    let serialize = (obj) => {
        var str = [];
        for (var p in obj)
          if (obj.hasOwnProperty(p)) {
            str.push(encodeURIComponent(p) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(obj[p]));
          }
        return str.join("&");
    }

    let insertValueToObj = (key, value, obj) => {        
            if(obj[key]){
                obj[key] = obj[key]+','+ value;
            }else{
                obj[key] = value;
            }
            return obj;
    }

    let createValueObj = (arr, obj, exceptinput) => {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject)=>{
            for (let index = 0; index < arr.length; index++) {          
                let isProperInput = exceptinput.includes(arr[index].type);                              
                if(!isProperInput) {
                    let key = arr[index].name;                        
                    let value = arr[index].value.trim();
                    obj = insertValueToObj(key, value, obj);                        
                } 
                if(index == (arr.length -1)){
                    resolve(obj);
                }                                      
            }
        });        
    }


});
```

thanks.